# error PARSING XML,UNBOUND PREFIX in manifest file

Tags: android

I have added a new dependency to my build.grade.after adding there is a error in my manifest.XML.the error is ERROR PARSING XML: UNBOUND PREFIX
Here is my manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
package="com.ravakri.wm" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.ravakri.wm.notesprovider"
        android:name=".NotesProvider"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ravakri.wm"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'  
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `> 500` questions already available in SO

Comment: add `</manifest>` to end of file

Comment: @AntonKovalyov,sorry it is already added in my manifest file but I forgot to copy it in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

manifest tag is not closed add

```
 </manifest>
```

in the last line of your manifest file